# Update object property for a given index range using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Let say I have an `ObservableCollection` called `ItemList` containing 10 objects. I want to update the `IsLocked` property for each object from index 5 to 10. How do I do this using `LINQ`?

Something like

```
ItemList.Where(x => x.IndexOf >= 5)
```

Then update their `IsLocked` property to `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LINQ` is for querying. Not updating. Use loops to manipulate your objects

```
foreach(var item in ItemList.Where((x,idx) => idx >= 5 && idx <= 10))
       item.IsLocked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible, but not good practice

```
ItemList.Skip(5).Take(5).ToList().ForEach(i => i.IsLocked = true);
```